# QApplication freeze sometimes, if i import QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebengineview, qapplication

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

print("0")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
print("1")
```

if i remove that line 
`from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView` 
there is no problem always output is 1 after 0 
if i put that line again 
`from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView` 
there is no output after 0

It hangs after a few tries.QApplication freeze rarely, if i import QWebEngineView

Attached is the screenshot. 
[ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auwdD.png) 
[ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHtE4.png)

op system Windows11 
PyQt5 version: 5.15.9, Qt version: 5.15.2 
PyQt6 version: 6.4.1, Qt version: 6.4.2

Comment: Are you using a venv or a virtual machine? Does this happens also when running the script in an external terminal or prompt (outside the IDE)?

Comment: thank you //

* no i am using real machine //
* i tried external terminal but same result //
* i deployed py to exe and execute with double click but same result //